# Consecutive Nouns

Tags: nouns

> She wanted pure cow milk.

In this sentence, is ***cow*** qualifying ***milk***? If so, should there be a comma after ***pure*** to write two adjectives one after the other?
Or is ***cow*** also a noun here? If so, is this a case of two nouns being used consecutively?

Comment: In addition to Barrie's answer, I suggest you read about [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), since that is what ‘cow’ is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it describes a bovine quadruped, *cow* is always a noun, but nouns can be used to modify other nouns, and here the noun *cow* modifies the noun *milk*. *Cow milk* has to be seen as a lexical whole, which in turn is modified by the adjective *pure*. There is thus no more need for a comma after *pure* than there would be if *cow* was absent.

If, however, *milk* was modified by two adjectives, then they would be separated by a comma, as in *pure, creamy milk*.

Comment: The phrase you want to look for is "noun compound". These are not "consecutive nouns"; they are unit noun phrases with specific meanings. There are many different kinds, frequently idiomatic, with quite different interpretations, like _pony ride_ and _snake bite_.